# Django updates that span relationships

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-related-manager

I would like to run an update query that spans several realtionships. Is this possible with django? This is what I have tried:

```
from django.db.models import F

Transaction.objects.filter(pk__lt=10).update(
    page__total_earned=F('page__total_earned')+5,
    page__profile__balance=F('page__profile__balance')+5
)
```

Here is a glimpse of my models in case you are wondering:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='transactions', null=True, blank=True)

class Page(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', related_name='pages', blank=True, null=True)
    total_earned = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Profile(models.Model):
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update).

```
Entry.objects.update(blog__name='foo') # Won't work!
```

> The update() method is applied instantly, and the only restriction on
>   the QuerySet that is updated is that it can only update columns in the
>   model’s main table, not on related models

So, the answer is not, you can't do it in that way.

Comment: Good eye. I am surprised I didn't see that. I'll accept it in 6 min.